# maven add project's jar lib to executable jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, executable-jar

I have a project containing the needed lib (jar files) in a sub directory (I'll refer to this as myLib) of the project. I want to build the project as an executable jar using maven with the dependencies from myLib to avoid ClassNotFoundException. What I'm planning to do is use maven-shade-plugin; however, most of the dependencies in myLib are not in the maven repository so I am not sure if I can do this without installing the myLib's jars in the maven repository:

```
    <artifactSet>
        <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
    <artifactSet>
```

Is it possible for maven to include these "myLib dependencies" to the packaged executable jar without installing them to the maven repository using mvn install:install?

I also tried to add the myLibs jar by moving them inside src/main/resources/ so they will be added in the executable jar file but I am not able to reference them by adding them in Class-Path header of my Manifest file as mentioned in docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just include 3rd party jars in your jar.  The classpath in the manifest is relative to the jar that you're are running.

For example, if you had `my-application.jar` that depended on `my-utils.jar` and both were in the same directory, your manifest classpath would be:

```
Class-Path: my-utils.jar
```

While if you were to move just `my-utils.jar` to a `lib` directory giving me this layout:

```
+ my-application.jar
+ lib
  + my-utils.jar
```

Your manifest classpath would be:

```
Class-Path: lib/my-utils.jar
```

Now to your problem.

First off, you should really get all your libs into a repository.  Maven is built to work from a repository and going against the 'Maven way' can often lead to problems later.

The alternative (which I don't recommend) is to declare the dependencies with `system` scope, which allows you to specify a path, for example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>lib/my-utils.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

However, use this with great care.  The `system` scope is intended to be used with system jars, typically those in the JVM.  Using it with anything else is really an abuse of this feature and is likely to impact the portablity of you build.

Once you have your dependencies straight you need to package your application.  As I mentioned, including dependencies jars in your application jar will not work.  I typically use the [Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) that allows me to create a zip, that can simply be unpacked to install the application.

The [Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) works from a simple descriptor, that in your case where you want to include your application jar plus the dependency jars, would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<assembly
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd"
>

  <id>${project.name}</id>

  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>

  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

  <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    <includes>
      <include>${artifact.groupId}:${artifact.artifactId}</include>
    </includes>
  </dependencySet>

  <dependencySet>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
  </dependencySet>

</assembly>
```

(You might need to play with the `include` a little)

You can also include scripts to run you application and an properties needed in the assembly.